# Lineal Transformation $T : V \rightarrow V$ injective implies that $T$ is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Show that if $V$ is a vector space over a finite-dimensional field $K$ and $T: V → V $ is a linear transformation, then if $T$ is injective it implies that $T$ is surjective.

Hi, I have been stuck with this problem can someone help me please?

Comment: Rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: You probably mean that $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space rather than $K$ a finite dimensional field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might look very complicated but its really not, I have just written everything in quite a lot of detail. So lets look at what the words we are going to be using mean:

$\textbf{Surjective:}$ "Everything in V can be reached from T". i.e for all v in V there is a x in V such that T(x) = v

$\textbf{Injective:} $ "If $v_1 \not = v_2 $ then $T(v_1) \not = T(v_2) $

For this proof we will the $\textbf{Rank-Nullity Theorem}$. This states that: Dimension(V) = Rank(T) + Nullity(T). Where Rank(T) and Nullity(T) are respectively the dimension of the Image and Kernal of T. Let us again define this two things.

$\textbf{Image:}$ This is the set of points that T maps to. i.e Image(T) = $\{ x \in V :  x = T(v)$ for some $v \in V \}$

$\textbf{Kernel:}$ This is the set of points that get mapped to $0_V$ i.e Kernal(T) ] $\{x \in V : T(x) = 0_V \} $

Clearly a map T is surjective if (and only if) the dimension of the image = dimension of the place it maps to. Firstly T maps V to itself so $T(V) \subset V $

Secondly Dim(T(V)) = Dim(V) $\implies $ T(V) = V

So all we have to do is prove that Dim(Image) (= Rank(T)) = Dim(V) and we are done. From the Rank Nullity theorem we could alternatively show: Nullity(T) = $0$ as Dimension(V) = Rank(T) + Nullity(T) from the RNT

We are given that T is injective and want to show that $T(v) = 0 \implies v = 0_V$ i.e the kernel = {0} and thus the Dimension(Kernel) = Nullity(T) = $0 $

Let us prove this via a contradiction. Assume that there is another element to the kernel, call it $k$ and this $k \not = 0_V$ And thus $T(k) = 0$ This violates that T is injective as $k \not = 0_V $ Yet $T(k) = T(0_V) = 0 $

Hence the $\textbf{Kernel} $ of T is {$0$} and thus the $\textbf{Nullity}$ of T, the Dimension of the $\textbf{Kernel}$, is also $0$ and thus from the $\textbf{Rank-Nullity Theorem}$ the Rank of T, the Dimension of the $\textbf{Image} $ = Dimension(V) - Nullity(T) = Dimension(V) and so $T(V) = V$ And thus it is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Take a basis $v_1,\dots,v_{\dim V}$ for $V$. Then, as $T$ injective, the vectors $Tv_1,\dots,Tv_{\dim V}$ are linearly independent$^1$, and hence, a basis for $V$. Thus, for every $v \in V$ there is $a_1,\dots,a_{\dim V} \in K$ such that $v = a_1Tv_1 + \cdots + a_{\dim V}Tv_{\dim V} = T(a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_{\dim V}v_{\dim V})$, which means that $T$ is surjective.

---

$^1$ To prove this use the fact that $Tw = 0$ implies $w=0$.